# Memory Leak on RAD Server for Linux when using dynamic arrays

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, ems

I'm using Delphi 10.3.1 and generated a sample application for a RAD Server Resource/Endpoint running on  Linux Ubuntu 18.04 under Apache 2.49. 
My application ProcessArray just creates two dynamic arrays which component is a record of 12 numeric fields. 
The size of these dynamics arrays is defined on run time when call the endpoint. 
During the execution this application allocates RAM memory as expected, BUT when it finishes it DOES NOT DEALLOCATES RAM !

If sucessive calls with arrays size as larger as 20 or 30 million, situation is even worst, because after finished run it still ramains allocated around 1GB per call leading to use SWAP area turning the machie very slow and unstable.

Depends on the number of calls , it can't run anymore and return an "out of memory" error message .

This issue **does not occurs when deploying to RAD Server running on Windows** .

**See my code :**

```
unit UntStru;

interface

Uses
       System.Threading,
       System.Classes;
Type
   TRec = record
         F1    : Integer;
         F2    : String;
         F5    : Real;
         F9    : Real;
         F10   : Real;
         // other Integer and Real fields
   End;

   TArrayRec        =  array of TRec;

   Function Process_array       (Var pArray1,pArray2   : TArrayRec; Const pfirst, plast : integer) : iTask;
   Function Process_arrayThread (Const pSize, pThreads : integer) : Integer;

implementation

Uses
    System.SysUtils,System.Diagnostics;

  Function Process_array    (Var pArray1,pArray2 : TArrayRec; Const pfirst, plast : integer) : iTask;
  var
      indx                : integer;
      larray1, larray2    : TArrayRec;
  begin
         // assigns var parameter array to local variable array because Ttask does not recognize var parameters
         lArray1 := pArray1;
         lArray2 := pArray2;

         // creates a Task to process arrays positions from pfirst to plast
         Result := TTask.Create
                   (
                      procedure
                       var
                          indx : integer;
                       begin
                             // scans array pArray from position pFirst through pLast
                             for indx := pFirst to pLast do
                             begin
                                   with lArray1[indx] do
                                   begin
                                        F1  := indx;
                                        F2  := 'Element  ' + indx.ToString;
                                        F5  := 2.5 * indx;
                                        F9  := 1.3 * indx;
                                        F10 := pLast;
                                   end;

                                   lArray2[indx] := lArray1[indx];
                             end;
                            // Just to assure that memory is being deallocated by the application
                            // This does not made any difference in deallocatin issue on Linux
                         {   Setlength(larray1,0);
                            Setlength(larray2,0);
                            FreeAndNil(larray1);
                            FreeAndNil(larray2);
                         }
                       end
                   );
  end;



  Function  Process_arrayThread (Const pSize, pThreads : integer) : Integer;
  var
      lvettask                  : array of iTask;
      lparray1, lparray2        : TArrayRec;
      ind, lsize, lstart, lend  : Integer;
   begin
        Try
            // array size in million
            lsize := 1000000 * pSize;

            // creates larray1 and set array size at once
            setlength(lparray1, lSize);

            //creates larray2 incrementing one by one
            for ind := 0  to lsize-1 do
            begin
                  setlength(lparray2,ind+1);
            end;

            // creates the array if iTasks according to number of Threads "pThreads"
            setlength(lvettask,pThreads);

            // creates slice size of array to be processed by each Thread
            lsize := lsize div pthreads;

            // creates each iTask on the array of iTasks
            for ind := 0 to pThreads-1 do
            begin
                 lstart := ind * lsize ;
                 lend   := (ind + 1) * lsize - 1 ;

                 lvettask[ind] := Process_array(lpArray1, lpArray2,lstart, lend);
            end;

            // starts each iTaks from array of iTasks
            for ind := 0 to pThreads-1 do
                lvetTask[ind].Start;

            // waits all iTasks been concluded
            TTask.WaitForAll(lvettask);
        Finally
            //
        End;
   end;

end.
```

**The Resource/Endpoint code is :**

```
unit UntProcessArray;    
// EMS Resource Module

interface    
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.JSON,
  EMS.Services, EMS.ResourceAPI, EMS.ResourceTypes;

type
  [ResourceName('ProcessArray')]
  TProcessArrayResource1 = class(TDataModule)
  published
    [ResourceSuffix('{item}')]
    procedure PutItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
  end;

implementation
{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}  {$R *.dfm}
Uses
   UntStru,System.Diagnostics;

procedure TProcessArrayResource1.PutItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
var
    LItem     : string;
    Linteger  : integer;
begin
      TRY
            LItem     := ARequest.Params.Values['item'];
            Linteger  := StrToint(Litem);

            // calls processing major function creating 4 threads
            Process_ArrayThread(Linteger,4);   

            AResponse.Body.SetValue(TJSONArray.Create('Message :','Concluded sucessfully'),True);
     Except
            on E:Exception do
            begin
                  AResponse.Body.SetValue(TJSONArray.Create('Mensagem', E.Message), True);
            end;
     End;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterResource(TypeInfo(TProcessArrayResource1));
end;

initialization
  Register;
end.
```

**Usage :  http://myLinuxUbuntuServer/ems-server/ProcessArray/30**  for a 30 milion array size

I still have doubts if this is really related to RAD Server 10.3.1 running on  Ubuntu Linux/Apache or if there  is something missing or wrong with  my code.

Does this happen on Delphi 10.3.2 new release too ?  (I appreciate if someone has this version installed and could test for me, before I proceed to the upgrade)

Does this happen on other Linux Distribution than Ubuntu ?

I highly appreciate your help guys ! Thks.

```
Edition 1:  
Environment info : 
IDE : Delphi Tokyo 10.3.1 Update 1 (version 26.0.33219.4899 ) 
Server : Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (64 bits) - 8GB RAM 8GB SWAP 
Kernel 4.15.0-1045-aws     
Web Server : Apache 2.4.29 RAD
Server bpl application compiled to Linux 64-bits
```

Screen shot of Linux server htop command Before first execution of

[image]

Screenshot of Linux server htop AFTER 6 executions of 
http://myLinuxUbuntuServer/ems-server/ProcessArray/20
[image]

Observe that RAM continues allocated in 5.30GB even after execution has finished.  Further calls to this endpoint will start from 5.30GB RAM and very quick will reach total RAM size (8GB) generating an "out of memory" error, or will use SWAP area and machine will become unstable and slow !

**Adding my .dproj file : Proj_ProcessArray.dproj**

```
package Proj_ProcessArray;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO OFF}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS OFF}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION ON}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO OFF}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES OFF}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE RELEASE}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$RUNONLY}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
  rtl,
  emsserverapi;

contains
  UntStru in 'UntStru.pas',
  UntProcessArray in 'UntProcessArray.pas' {ProcessArrayResource1: TDataModule};

end.
```

**Adding a Console Application ProcessArrayConsole for Linux 64, that uses the same Unit published above  unit UntStru**

```
program ProcessArrayConsole;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  UntStru in 'UntStru.pas';

var
   lsize   : integer;
   lstraux : string;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }

    // get size of array in millions
     lsize := ParamStr(1).tointeger ;

    // call Process_ArrayThread using 4 threads
    Process_arrayThread(lsize,4);

    lstraux := FloatToStrF(lsize * 1000000,ffnumber,10,0);

    Writeln;
    Writeln('Concluded to process two arrays of ' + lstraux + ' positions.');
    Writeln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I ran this console application on the same Linux Server, calling several times 
 ./ProcessArrayConsole 30   and RAM was totally freed after execution !!.

So that, it seems that only when I use EMS Apache module or EMSDevServer (stand alone) this deallocation issue occurs.

The only exception happened when I ran 3 calls of 30 million size simultaneously. In this case total 8GB RAM was consumed and SWAP area started to be used, but achie got very slow and the three process is taking a long time to conclude. (still running after 12 minutes) .

Comment: @Dalija Prasnikar , could you take a look at on this , please ? Thks.

Comment: It would greatly help if a minimal example could be created.

Comment: @David, I'm sorry but I didn't get your point completely. Besides the above code and explanations, what other  "minimal example"  could I provide here?  Or do you mean that  my code too big ?  Or should I upload some screenshots of the memory usage ?

Comment: A [mcve] would be much more helpful.

Comment: @David , I reviewed my code, removed unnecessary parts that measured time and let only the ones related to the key issue. This code is executable and can reproduce the problem. Thanks for the instructions.  I hope I can get some help now.

Comment: The code isn't really executable now. A single dpr file with a complete program. Please follow the link I gave you to learn more about what a [mcve] is. Of course Remy is right that your code leaks a string list every time you call Process_arrayThread. It's also a little disturbing to see you try to call Free on a dynamic array.

Comment: @David, I added the .dproj file Proj_ProcessArray.dproj . I have no .dpr for this project.  I removed Tstrings as function return and replaced by an integer.  The problem of memory leak remaisn the same, that was not the cause.  Thanks !

Comment: That's not a [mcve]. It's very far from being minimal. I suspect that Remy is right that you are misdiagnosing this as a leak. But we can only guess. Part of you learning how to tackle problems like this is you learning how to strip this down to a truly minimal, yet complete, reproduction.

Comment: @David, I have no problem to learn new things and appreciate any suggestions . As my Delphi knowlege allow me to do now, I consider the code I posted as minimal to reproduce the issue.  If I remove more parts I run the risk to not represent whole problem.   Would mind to be more clear and tell me straight what should I remove or add in order for you to consider this minimal and reproducible !   So that I can learn (I hope) and avoid such behaviour next time I ask for support in this forum !  I appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: Make a console application that reproduces the behaviour. And I don't believe that your code is truly minimal.

Comment: @David, this is a RAD Server package bplProj_ProcessArray.so which runs on Linux/Apache and you mues call it through a url like  http://your_ linuxserver/ems-server/ProccessArray.  I'm sorry but I realy don't  know a way to generate RAD Server package as a console application !  Any help is welcome too !  Correct me if I'm wrong, no probelm with this.

Comment: like others have said code is far from minimal to get the idea what is going on. I never used EMS, so there is additional code that might play role in your problem that I am not familiar with. However, one line sounds particularly suspicious (loop actually)  `setlength(lparray2,ind+1)` what are you trying to accomplish with that running in a loop? If nothing else this will create nice memory fragmentation.

Comment: Surely you have the tools to create console applications. I guess RAD server is the host for your package, but there must be a way to compile the same code into a form where others can inspect it.

Comment: And indeed `for ind := 0  to lsize-1 do
            begin
                  setlength(lparray2,ind+1);
            end;` does look pretty weird. What is wrong with `SetLength(lparray2, lsize);`?

Comment: @Dalija, thanks for replying !  This line SetLength(lparray2,ind+1)  is used just to  compare the time to create an array one position each time with creation at once   using SetLength(lparray2, lsize).  Although this is a sample code, I do have such loop in my real application because I do not know the array size in advance.  "@David"  I think  your question on the Setlenght is answered with this post here.

Comment: @David , I'll generate a console application with the major functions only . In few minutes I post here.

Comment: BTW are you sure Delphi for Linux uses FastMM4? isn't it using the libc malloc/free (as on Android+iOS) ? I don't have Delphi Linux, so I can't check.

Comment: @Arnaud, I don't know if Delphi for Linux uses FastMM4 . Sorry.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez You are right. Delphi uses FastMM4 only on Windows [Memory Management](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Memory_Management)

Comment: Your console application does not prove (or disprove) anything. When process finishes memory is automatically reclaimed by the OS. The only way to prove your code with arrays has leaks is that you run that code within console application more than once (and observe how memory behaves, before the console application ends). I would try that myself, but I don't have Linux setup at the moment.

Comment: @Dalija, thks for the remarks.  I did this already few minutes ago.  I ran the console aplication and observed that RAM was allocaed in 3,4 5 GB during execution and totally released when aplication ends.  This did not happen when I ran under Apache  or under EMSDevServer.  I checked memory before, during and at the end of execution. It behaves as I expected : allocates durign execution and release after finished.

Comment: @Dalija, if you will set up a Linux machine and install PAServer and RAD Server (EMS) , allow me to suggest you to use another distribution than Ubuntu 18.04, once in this distribution is having the current behaviour.  It would be useful to know if this issue also happens in other distributions (CentOS, Red Hat, Suse, ...)  . Thanks for your help !

Comment: Sorry, my development machine is cramped at the moment and I don't have room to make Linux VM. Setting up separate Linux machine would be even more problematic. There is no reason (at least no obvious one) why dynamic arrays would not be deallocated on Linux, so either you misdiagnosed the problem or the issue is somewhere else. I would suggest using some memory tools like [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) for deeper analysis.

Comment: @Dalija, only today, after  the discussions made here I tested this application in directly in Linux console without EMSDevServer and without Apache (ems_module). For my surprise it worked fine,  i.e. no memory remained allocated when the application has finished. Based on that, it leads me to think that this issue is related to EMS Server or Apache ems module. Does this conclusion  make sense for you ?

Comment: Sounds more like a memory fragmentation issue caused my malloc rather than a memory leak.

Comment: You have to fine tune your Apache server:
https://serverfault.com/questions/68410/a-question-of-memory-for-an-apache-server/68427#68427

Comment: @StefanGlienke Current POSIX libc malloc/free heap is very good, and doesn't suffer from memory fragmentation more than FastMM4. Probably less, since its source code (based on ptmalloc2 proven library) is pretty impressive and efficient - see https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html

Comment: The real question may be: is anyone using RadServer for Linux on production, hosted in Apache, with some memory aggressive behavior, and no problem?

Comment: @Arnaud, yeaah good point !  So I'm using RAD Server for Linux hosted on Apache and I'm planning to go live on production as soon as I solve this issue.  That is why I'm asking help from you in here!

Comment: Thank you all that tried help me on this RAD Server / Linux Apache memory issue. Unfortunately I still haven't no clear solution.  In the last days I've been studying Apache MPM parameters configuration  but with no sucessful results.  I'm changing my strategy to work with RAD Server /Apache, therefore  I'll keep on it only  REST JSON calls to the Resources/Endpoint and do the intensive processing/memory parts on a Linux Console Application, until I got a better solution.  Thank so much for your  ideas, questions, alerts and directions!

Comment: Hint: instead of a console application, consider using an alternative solution for running Server code on Linux, e.g. using FPC and our Open Source mORMot. You can still use Delphi and Windows, but you can cross-compile to Linux the very same source. Performance and stability (also RAM consumption) is awesome on Linux for some of our projects running for months, handling TBs of data over thousands of concurrent connections, with no restart. It is self hosted, easily daemonized, and we usually put a nginx reserve proxy in front of it. Much better approach than Apache to my opinion.

Comment: @Arnaud, it sounds good to me, thanks!  I'll take a look at on that too.

Comment: It can be related to this:
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-32426 You may try implementing the suggested workaround and see if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

> During the execution this application allocates RAM memory as expected, BUT when it finishes it DOES NOT DEALLOCATES RAM !

Delphi's memory manager allocates memory from the OS in blocks, and caches freed memory for reuse in later allocations, it is not returned back to the OS. So, if you are measuring leaking by how memory is being allocated from the OS, this is not the way to diagnose leaks. Use the memory manager's own built-in leak reporting feature instead.

That being said, your `Process_arrayThread()` returns a `TStringList` object as output, but I don't see you freeing it.

Comment: thansk for the reply!  This Tstrings was returned in my original program and I forgot to remove it from here.  I changed the function now to return an integer.  This was not the problem, I'm sure.    I'm measuring the non deallocated memory by checking htop command in Linux and observing that, after program executes a portio of RAm continue being allocated and after 5 or 5 consecutives call the the endpoint, RAM used increases and remains as used.   See the screenshots of htop.

Comment: Your statement is not accurate. The memory is returned back to the OS with some threshold - at least by any good MM like FastMM4 and libc free(). Achieving GBs of RAM when memory is low under Windows with the very same code sounds like a memory leak to me, or a RadServer bug when implementing the Apache .so library.

Comment: @Remy , do you have Delphi 10.3.2 and  RAD Server on Linux running ? If so, could you run the sample code I uploaded above and check if this issue remains the same in this  latest release ?   Thanks.

Comment: @JRG no, I do not

Answer (score 0):

You have to fine tune your Apache server.

Please, take a look on this discussion below (it's for PHP, but applies to any environment):

https://serverfault.com/questions/68410/a-question-of-memory-for-an-apache-server/68427#68427

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable here. Please take the essence of the link and add it here.